# Python appending values from one dictionary to another with the same keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary

Evening,

I'm trying to append another set of values to the same set of keys in a dictionary.

currently, I pull the some postcode attributes from an api which stores the request in a dictionary and returns the outcome in a dataframe. But If I wanted to return another postcode attributes from the same api how would I append the values from it to the same dictionary so they appear as a second row in the dataframe.

current bit of code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://api.getthedata.com/postcode/ST87HL"
req = requests.get(url)
data = req.json()
entries = data["data"]

df = pd.DataFrame([entries])
print(df)
```

Really appreciate all the help, thank you.

Comment: Just make a list of dictionaries, and keep appending new responses to it.

Comment: do you mean something like this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-append/ after you have first created your first dataframe or you could just create a list object with the data that you want and then put that list into the dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your postcodes in the list, iterate over this list and append result into another list. As last step, create a DataFrame from this list:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

postcodes = ["ST87HL", "ST87EZ"]

all_data = []
for p in postcodes:
    url = "https://api.getthedata.com/postcode/{}".format(p)
    req = requests.get(url)
    data = req.json()
    entries = data["data"]
    all_data.append(entries)


df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  postcode status usertype  easting  northing  positional_quality_indicator  country   latitude  longitude postcode_no_space postcode_fixed_width_seven postcode_fixed_width_eight postcode_area postcode_district postcode_sector outcode incode
0  ST8 7HL   live    small   388982    357799                             1  England  53.117254  -2.166072            ST87HL                    ST8 7HL                   ST8  7HL            ST               ST8           ST8 7     ST8    7HL
1  ST8 7EZ   live    small   389017    358349                             1  England  53.122198  -2.165568            ST87EZ                    ST8 7EZ                   ST8  7EZ            ST               ST8           ST8 7     ST8    7EZ
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was after, thank you for the quick response.